# Representing the total derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, article-writing

This is a quick question about syntax.

I have the function:

$$\hat{x_i} = \frac{x_i - \mu_\beta}{\sqrt{\sigma^2_\beta+\epsilon}}$$

where $\sigma^2_\beta$ is an intermediate function:

$$\sigma^2_\beta = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(x_i-\mu_\beta)^2$$

The functions themselves are *not* relevant, I just included them for clarity. **If I wanted to write out finding the derivative of $\frac{\partial{\hat{x_i}}}{\partial{\mu}}$, do I write it like this?**

$$\frac{\partial{\hat{x_i}}}{\partial{\mu}} = \frac{\partial{\hat{x_i}}}{\partial{\mu}} + \frac{\partial{\hat{x_i}}}{\partial{\sigma^2}} \cdot \frac{\partial{\sigma^2}}{\partial{\mu}}$$

I feel like it looks confusing because I have $\frac{\partial{\hat{x_i}}}{\partial{\mu}}$ on both sides of the equal sign, so it could be difficult to interpret. Is there an alternative way to show that I'm trying to take the **total** derivative of the function as $\mu$ is in two arguments of $\hat{x_i}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I feel like it looks confusing because I have ∂xi^∂μ on both sides of the equal sign, so it could be difficult to interpret.

One is made with *no* independent variables constrained, the other made while constraining occurrences of $\sigma_\beta$ (treating it as though independent of $\mu_\beta$).

Too many authors leave this to context, but they should mark the distinction to avoid this confussion.

---

You may use the total derivative symbols, since that *is* what you are doing.

$$\large\dfrac{\mathrm d \hat x_i}{\mathrm d \mu_\beta}=\dfrac{\partial\hat x_i}{\partial \mu_\beta}+\dfrac{\partial\hat x_i}{\partial (\sigma_\beta^2)}\dfrac{\mathrm d(\sigma_\beta^2)}{\mathrm d\mu_\beta}$$

$\dfrac{\mathrm d \hat x_i}{\mathrm d \mu_\beta}$ is the total derivative of $\hat x_i$ with respect to $\mu_\beta$ (as the lone independent variable). Ie the derivative when no other independent variables are constrained.

$\dfrac{\partial\hat x_i}{\partial \mu_\beta}$ is the partial derivative of $\hat x_i$ with respect to $\mu_\beta$ while keeping $\sigma_\beta$ constrained.

---

Alternatively, you might indicating the set of independent variables being constrained.

$$\large\dfrac{\partial \hat x_i}{\partial \mu_\beta}=\left.\dfrac{\partial\hat x_i}{\partial \mu_\beta}\right\vert_{(\sigma_\beta^2)}+\left.\dfrac{\partial\hat x_i}{\partial (\sigma_\beta^2)}\right\vert_{\mu_\beta}\left.\dfrac{\partial(\sigma_\beta^2)}{\partial\mu_\beta}\right.$$

In this case, a partial derivative with no constrained independent variables is a total derivative.

---

You may also combine these approaches.

---

Alternatively you have functions $f( m, s), g(m)$ and define $\bar x_i=f(\mu_\beta, g(\mu_\beta))$ then::

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d\bar x_i}{\mathrm d\mu_\beta}= f_1(\mu_\beta, g(\mu_\beta))+f_2(\mu_\beta, g(\mu_\beta))\cdot g_1(\mu_\beta)$$

Where $f_1, f_2$ are partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to the first or second arguments, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the different examples for notation! For the notation of the total derivative for your first example using $\frac{\mathrm d\hat{x_i}}{\mathrm d\mu_\beta}$, is this syntax identical to the univariate derivative? Is it expected for the reader to acknowledge it is the total derivative because I also show partials? e: I see the MathJax is a little small, I'm trying to refer to $\mathrm d$

Comment: Yes.  When a function is univariate, the total derivative is identical to the ordinary derivative.  In this case, $\bar x_i$ is presented as a bivariate function of $\mu_\beta$ and $\sigma_\beta$ *but* $\sigma_\beta$ itself is function of the former; so $\bar x_i$ is actually univariate.